# How to ignore time in NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

My class has a datetime field called date_time.
In the following loop I wish to find all instances that have the same date, where time shall be ignored.

```
for (int day=0; day < days.length; day++) {
     [components setDay:day];
     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date_time == %@", [cal dateFromComponents:components]];

}
```

The predicate above won't work though, because date_time contains also the time.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: It is bit difficult to make sense from above posted code snippet, would you mind posting bit more related code?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you:

```
[components setDay:day];
NSDate *dateFromComponents = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
NSDate *nextDayDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:24.0*60.0*60.0
                                            sinceDate:dateFromComponents];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date_time >= %@ && date_time < %@",
                              dateFromComponents, nextDayDate] ;
```